# External HDD detected, but doesn't have drive letter or show up in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, external-hard-drive

Today my Kodi HTPC, a Revo RL80 (Intel Celeron 1007 1.5GHz, 2GB RAM), gave me the option of upgrading to Windows 10. I thought I'd give it a go. I backed up Kodi and other such things and upgraded. The whole process was easy and quite fast.

Until I sat down to watch some TV! Kodi couldn't find any TV episodes. I checked Windows Explorer and my 6 month old Seagate 4TB Backup Plus external HDD was missing. I checked Device Manager and Disk Management and the HDD shows up, but does not have a drive letter assigned to it. I've checked/updated the drivers, installed software recommended by Seagate and I've followed their [troubleshooting steps](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/006169en?language=en_US), but still no luck. I've also tried disabling Fast Boot, as recommened [here](http://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/17210-windows-10-cant-find-external-usb-3-0-drives-2.html?s=d4aa3b4f713b22f3e8ae3083ecaea2ba) but I don't seem to have that option so couldn't.

The drive is recognised (Windows bongs when the drive is attached/removed, and I have the option to 'Safely Remove...') and I can feel/hear it whir. I've attached the HDD to my MacBook, a Dell laptop and a Samsung laptop and i get the same problems.

Please please help! I refuse to give in and format the HDD as I have 3TB+ of data on it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign it a drive letter to the external HDD. Open Disk Management and right click on the drive and chose `Change drive Letters And Paths...` Then assign it an open drive letter from the menu. The new assignment should stick through reboots/shutdowns/disconnects.

Comment: I thought of that, but that option is greyed out.

Comment: I had to do this for a printer's card reader once. Eject the disk, shut down, unplug the HDD, boot up, remove the drive from computer management, shut down, plug in, assign new drive letter. Not sure if that is the case this time but worth a shot, otherwise I am stumped.